# Javascript dont run on a php file

Tags: javascript, php, function

I want to run a script on a PHP file, but it is not running. It runs the header before the function runs so don't know how to run first the script

```
iniciales();
header('Location: Lista_libros.php');//This runs before the funtion

function iniciales(){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("test");
</script>';
}
```

Comment: You are a bit short on useful context in this question

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) **like you were asked to when you registered**
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This could well be a [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: `header()` won't work if there's content before. Try redirecting from your JS

Answer (score 0):

it will actually run, but you can't see it because of redirection,
well, if the server sends a redirection header, the browser redirects and therefore "changes the URL", so your alert and other kinds of stuff will be wiped out from the screen

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side script language.
JavaScript is client side script language.

So in your case if you want to run JavaScript code try redirecting from your JavaScript and remove header function form PHP code .
If you do this so your JavaScript code can execute .

Comment: Unless you use `node.js`... then Javascript is a server-side script language as well ;)

Comment: Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform, back-end JavaScript runtime environment that runs on a JavaScript Engine and executes JavaScript code outside a web browser